# What is the best way to load the WP environment in a subdomain of my multisite Wordpress install?

Tags: multisite, customization, wp-load.php, subdomains

I have a subfolder install of WP multisite, let's say at "domain.com".

I now need to load the WP environment in subdomains of domain.com, say "sub1.domain.com", "sub2.domain.com", ... "subN.domain.com". Note that these subdomains do not correspond to WP blogs. But I do need to have access to the logged in user, the database, etc.

I have set up wildcard subdomains to load a php file that will display what I need for any particular subdomain, and I am including "wp-load.php" early in that file. The problem is that near line 99 in "ms-settings.php" it redirects to the main page of the site because $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST'] is the subdomain, not the main site domain.

So how can I load the WP environment correctly in a non-blog subdomain?

I have a prototype that works, but I'm worried about the side effects of what I'm doing so it would be great if someone who's familiar with the core could weigh in.

What I am doing is pre-populating the $current_site and $current_blog globals appropriately before including "wp-load". Then, "ms-settings" doesn't try to create these and doesn't hit the code path that detects the subdomain and redirects to the front page.

I can now access member information (e.g. using 'get_userdata') and $wpdb.

Does this seem like a reasonable approach?

Comment: Trying to think of a more clear wording for this question without it getting too lengthy. Maybe "How to load WP environment in subdomain without Multisite taking over?"

Comment: Sure, if you prefer short to accurate. :) I should probably add "multisite" though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the defines to make it pick the site you want it to pick.

You can define these four to setup the $current_site values properly: DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE, PATH_CURRENT_SITE, SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE, BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE.

If you check the wpmu_current_site() function in ms-load.php, you'll see that it uses those to create the $current_site global.

You may or may not have to populate the $current_blog global manually. Not sure. Try it and see.

So realistically, all you have to do is add something like this before you call wp-load.php:

```
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

With the right values for your main example.com site, of course.

If you don't want to put these in the sub-domain's php files themselves, then you can do something like this in either the wp-config.php or the sunrise.php file (if you define SUNRISE to true in the wp-config.php as well, of course).

```
if ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'sub1.example.com' || 
     $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'sub2.example.com') {
    define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com' );
    define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
    define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
    define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
}
```

That's pretty much what the sunrise file load is there for, to allow a place where you can manually override things like this. Advantage of using sunrise.php over wp-config.php for it (which also works) is that you can easily turn sunrise on and off somewhere else, for testing and debugging and such.

Comment: Thanks Otto. This looks like exactly what I need. I'll give it a try and report back here.

Answer (score 2):

You could give a try to [Wordpress Mu Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin.

**Update**

Actually, it better fits on your request to include `wp-blog-header.php` in the top of your php file of your subdomain, so you can load also the template functions.

```
    include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../path_to_my_blog/wp-blog-header.php");
```

Or you can do a [wp_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) after the include of `wp-load.php`

Comment: @konus Maybe give on example of *how* he could use the plugin ...

Comment: @EAMAnn Actually, the plugin load the main blog completely in a subdomain. Reading twice, I understand that the question want to avoid that. **Sorry for that** :-/

Comment: @konus, Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't really address the question I am asking. I don't need the template functions so wp-load is fine in that respect. Also, the wp_redirect doesn't address the problem I am having. ms-settings is redirecting before it even gets to "after wp-load.php". Like I say in the question, one solution is to pre-populate the $current_site and $current_blog globals and I would like to know whether that might have any adverse side effects.

Comment: @greg, You say _"I do need to have access to the logged in user, the database, etc."_. By including `wp-blog-header.php` you will able to do everything you want (instantiate `$wpdb`, load specifics `wp-` functions, etc. and also template functions). You could also use [switch_to_blog](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/switch_to_blog) when you want specific info from one blog in particular.

Comment: @konus, I do understand this. But I get what I need using wp-load. **That is not the issue**. Regardless of whether I user wp-load or wp-blog-header I will have the same problem of a redirect because the subdomain != primary domain. I guess what I'm saying is that your answer, while perhaps another interesting thing to debate, is not relevant to my question about ms-settings, which is loaded regardless. Or am I missing something? Are you saying that wp-blog-header somehow does solve the specific problem I am talking about.

Comment: @greg Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but using `wp-blog-header.php` in your php code, you'll **not** be redirected, isn't relevant if you are in a subdomain or an external path. When you include the correct file (in a WP installation path) you will able to do all your queries in WP syntax.

Comment: @konus, I think you are mistaken. Using `wp-blog-header.php` makes no difference -- the same redirect occurs (I've confirmed this by testing). If you look at the source, the only differences between `wp-blog-header.php` and `wp-load.php` are that the former sets `$wp_did_header` and requires the template loader.

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting the same thing as asked in this question and could not get around the redirect until I spoofed the $_SERVER vars before I included wp-load.php:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', $siteRow['domain'] );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', $siteRow['wp_blog_id'] );

$_SERVER = array(
    "HTTP_HOST" => $siteRow['domain'],
    "SERVER_NAME" => $siteRow['domain'],
    "REQUEST_URI" => "/",
    "REQUEST_METHOD" => "GET"
);
```

The $siteRow array is my own site config, update the variables with what you need.
No redirect, and all WP functions at your disposal! Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I currently use a switch statement to set the DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE

I set it up to work when deployed on the live server.
The switch also sets DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE for when I'm working locally on my development machine. (thus all the .dev top level domains)

After the switch statement, I define the other things that don't change but are MULTISITE related.

```
switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
    case 'sub1.mydomain.com':
    case 'sub2.mydomain.com':
    case 'community.mydomain.com':
        define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'community.mydomain.com');
        break;
    case 'sub1.mydomain.dev':
    case 'sub2.mydomain.dev':
    case 'community.mydomain.dev':
        define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'community.mydomain.dev');
        break;
    default:
        define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'community.mydomain.com');
        break;
}

define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Of course this wp-config.php file has more settings in it, but I didn't include those because they aren't specific to WP MULTISITE installs.

Note: When working locally (after downloading the latest sql file. I need to do massive search-replace operations on the database, it's slightly unrelated to your specific question, but I'm going to leave the wp-cli.org snippet below)

```
wp search-replace 'community.mydomain.com' 'community.mydomain.dev' --network --dry-run
wp search-replace 'sub1.mydomain.com' 'sub1.mydomain.dev' --network --dry-run
wp search-replace 'sub2.mydomain.com' 'sub2.mydomain.dev' --network --dry-run
```